# Did you mean for Android

Tags: android, search

For example, I have an array and for search operation in this array, I want to use "did you mean" of Google. I want to learn if I have a chance to use this.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a question. It is also completely unclear what you are talking about.

Comment: He wants to set his program up so if a user types something close to whats in the array the program will suggest the correct thing

Comment: I have an array and when user searches a string, I want to suggest correct things as @mpeerman said, such Google's "did you mean" for web searches. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`AutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).